# Convert a series of typedefs to a char array

Tags: c++, c, casting

Thanks in advance for the help.
trying to use a fairly large C/Cpp (yes I know) library and am running into an error.  Unfortunately the error that I am getting back is extremely vague but I do know what variable is causing it.  All I would like to do is simply print this variable out to stdout so that I can see what is going on.  However, this variable is not a standard type.  It has the type

```
 Opt_Int64 someVar = 10;
```

where

```
typedef int64_t VosT_int64;
typedef VosT_Int64 OpT_Int64;
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to convert this Opt_Int64 type into a char array so that I can print it out.  I would assume that the following function would do this for me

```
void int64ToChar(char mesg[], Opt_Int64 num) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) mesg[i] = num >> (8-1-i)*8;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work (I built a very simple hello world style program to test this).  Either I simply don't understand typedef as well as I should or there must be something wrong with the function above.  Isn't typedef just a way of telling the compiler that you're giving a type a different name?

Comment: It looks like you are (incorrectly) trying to convert a 64 bit integer into 8 separate integers of 8 bits each, none of which have anything at all to do with a human readable string, which is what people think you want when you talk about using \n and char. If that's what you do want, you are in serious trouble. :)

Comment: How would you convert an `int` to a char array...?

Comment: I would call it a BYTE array if it were just broken down for mathematical operations, maybe for encryption?  That's basically what he seems to be attempting. To get a printable string is completely different, and that's covered in Brian's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int64_t` is a standard type, defined in `stdint.h`. You can print it like this:

```
printf("%" PRId64 "\n", someVar);
```

The macro `PRId64` and its kin are defined in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: I have to convert it to a char array first since the library isn't using a standard io function such as printf.  Ideally, I like to pass add this char array to the error message that is being printed.  Otherwise I'll have to hack something up (ie writing the result to a file).

Comment: Even besides this point though, what I have should work unless I'm missing something trivial correct?

Comment: @Ryan You can use `sprintf` then

Comment: @Ryan Can you explain what exactly you expect your `int64ToChar` function to do?

Comment: int64_t should be a signed 64 bit number.  int64ToChar should take this 64 bit number and place it into a 9 byte char array where the last char is '\n'.  Do you think this is where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Ryan So the first 7 bytes in your example will be `\0`? That might be your issue. Also, keep in mind that overflowing into `char` causes implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: yea that must be it.  I just used sprintf with the PRId64 macro and it worked fine.  Just a stupid mistake lol.  I'm glad to know that I do in fact understand typedef though haha.  Thanks for the help.